# Nodejs doesn't save hashed password to mysql db

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

New to NodeJS, trying to write user registration by my own, but facing a trouble when app saves non-hashed password. Tried to check if password is hashed before saving and alert says it is. Here's my code:

```
var userData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

        var user = userData;

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                user.password = hash;
                alert(user.password); //shows hashed password
            });

        //skipped connection code

        database.connection.query("insert into users set ?", user, function(err){ //saves non-hashed password
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log("successfull");

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bcrypt.hash` is asynchronous. You have what is essentially a race condition in your code.

```
    database.connection.query("insert into users set ?", user, function(err){ //saves non-hashed password
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log("successfull");

    });
```

When you pass `user` to this method, `user.password` has not yet been populated by the `bcrypt.hash` callback.

You'll need to put the query logic in the bcrypt callback if you stick with a callback oriented style, though most javascripters would likely use promises or async/await (which should be available natively in most recent releases of Node.js).

```
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            user.password = hash;
            alert(user.password); //shows hashed password

            //>>query logic should go here.
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to put the database query inside the callback. Try something like this:

```
    var userData = {
       email: req.body.email,
       password: req.body.password
    }

    var user = userData;

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
         if(err) console.log(err);
         user.password = hash;
         database.connection.query("insert into users set ?", 
            user, function(err){ //saves non-hashed password
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log("successfull");
        });
    });
```

Node.js is asynchronous like that. That is why there are callback functions. You are inserting the user before you have hashed the password or those events happened at the same time. Basically, you have a race condition.